# How to authenticate to azure/msal from chrom extension? Problem with "redirect_uri"

Tags: javascript, azure, google-chrome-extension, azure-ad-msal

I have a web app where users can login through azure-msal and assign certain data to their and other users accounts. I would also like to create google chrome extension which connects to this data assigned to their accounts.

For this I would like to authenticate users to this extension through azure-msal as well. But I have a problem where I cannot assign redirect URI from chrome extension since it doesn't start with "https".

I've found multiple posts from 2-4 years ago which suggest it used to be possible to authenticate to msal using chrome uxtension. Is it still possible and I'm just missing something obvious or it's just plain impossible and I should try different approach?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible and isn't the recommended way when working with chrome extensions as well. You should instead use the [`chrome.identity`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/) APIs to perform authentication which solves the problem with the rediect URI scheme as well.

Refer to [this sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/ChromiumExtensionSample) from the Azure MSAL JS library for more information on how to use the `chrome.identity` APIs with the MSAL JS library.